# Transition matrix in Tableau

Tags: matrix, transition, tableau-api

I want to create a transition matrix in tableau with the following data as example.

```
IDKEY Status Date
A       1     2013
B       1     2013
C       2     2013
D       1     2013
A       1     2014
B       1     2014
C       1     2014
D       2     2014
```

From this data I want to build a simple matrix. Rows are Current Status and Columns are Previous status. [1,2] means for example: 33%(C) of the ID's which have a current status of
1 had a previous status of 2. And the ID with a current status of 2(D) had a previous status of 1.

```
      [,1] [,2]
  [1,]0.67  0.33
  [2,]1     0
```

Any ideas on this? I tried several calculated fields but they do not seem to work.

---

For additional information, see the attached screenshot. [image: Transition]

Loan A&B remain 3 during 2014. I want to give those loans a value like "33" and loan
I goes from 1 to 2 and I want that loan to get a value "12". For example in a new column.

This example is with more levels than the first one.

Comment: There might be a way to do those calculations directly in Tableau, but it's not worth it. Should use SQL (or Access, or Excel, even TAbleau) to build a better suited table, each entry being one Loan ID, one column for 2013 values and one for 2014 values. Then you life would be easier, and you could do those calculations on this new table using Tableau easily

Comment: Basically export the table you created (the screenshot) and connect to it

Comment: Thanks Inox, that is indeed the way I solved the issue a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into this. And wrote a note on the solution for this exact problem.
http://vizdiff.blogspot.com/2016/10/creating-markov-chain-transition-matrix.html

The calculation in Tableau is actually very easy. We just need to compute the row totals along the new states. One can use Either `window_sum()` or LOD the level of details. See the details in the above article.

`Sum({Fixed Year13: Sum(Number of Records)})` or `Window_Sum(Sum(Number of Records))` computing using Year14.

See if this answer after 2 years works for you.